# Putting Tableview inside UITableViewCell Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, nested

I'm having trouble with putting a tableview inside a uitableview cell. Right now, it doesn't even display the nested tableview. I set the tableview's delegates and datasource to the custom cell, and have all the required methods. I am also using a storyboard for my tableviews, and have connected all outlets properly.

The problem is that it does not go into the cellForRow function. It does, however, go into the numberOfRowsInSection function, and also the heightForRow function. Below is the code for the custom cell that holds the nested UITableviewcell.

```
import UIKit

class EventSurveyCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var cellBox: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var announcementLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var authorLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numVotesLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var surveyArray: [SurveyClass] = []

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func do_table_refresh()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return
    })
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("cellforrow")
    let cell: SurveyItemCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("surveyItemCell") as! SurveyItemCell!

    cell.itemLabel.text = surveyArray[indexPath.row].itemName

    //go through firebase to check which one user voted on
    cell.voteButton.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "circle")

    let percent = surveyArray[indexPath.row].numOfVotes/surveyArray[indexPath.row].totalNumOfVotes
    cell.precentLabel.text = String(percent)

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    print("heightforrow")
    return 44
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("numrowsinsection")
    return 3
    //should be return self.surveyArray.count. 

}
}
```

Below is a snippet of code for in the the viewcontroller that is holding the custom cells (containing nested tableviews). This code is part of the cellforrowatindexpath

```
   case PostType.survey:

        let cell: EventSurveyCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventSurveyCell") as! EventSurveyCell!
        //cut out other code as it is irrelevant
        cell.surveyArray = eventPost.surveyClassArray

        cell.do_table_refresh()
        print(cell.tableView.rowHeight)

        return cell
```

Another problem I have noticed is that when printing cell.tableview.rowheight, it prints -1. This could be the reason why it does not enter cellforrowatindexpath, but I clearly return 44 in the heightforrow function. Right now, it doesnt even display the nested tableview.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) Don't need `do_table_refresh`, you can call `cell.tableView.reloadData()` directly.

2) Override the systemLayoutSizeFitting:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority function:

```
override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {

    tableView.reloadData()

    // if the table view is the last UI element, you might need to adjust the height
    let size = CGSize(width: targetSize.width,
                      height: tableView.frame.origin.y + tableView.contentSize.height)
    return size

}
```

3) In your view controller, after you set the `surveyArray`, remove this line `cell.do_table_refresh()`,  replace with `cell.setNeedsLayout()` to auto adjust the layout (you might also need to call a method to update the other UIs such as announcementLabel etc. call it before setNeedsLayout too.)

Comment: I have tried this, this works for single line label inside nested tableview Cell, but what if we have multiline label inside our nested tableview Cell ?

Comment: if you have multiple labels, you can use UIStackView to host all the labels.

Comment: Was using iOS 8 , no stackview available

Comment: Literally spent so long trying to figure this out and this worked! You're literally the best! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, **cellForRow** was not being called for the TableView Inside Custom Cell. And the reason was that the tableview had no **height** set for it to show the content inside it. After I set some height for the child TableView, cellForRow started to begin calling.